# Как получить название ключа из значения этого ключа? JS

Tags: javascript

Как вместо **['firstName'], ['lastName']** динамически подставлять названия ключей (firstName, lastName)?
Пример кода:

```
validate: values => {
        let errors = {
            firstName: baseValidate({
                validationType: 'name',
                validationValue: values['firstName'],
                onEmptyErrorMessage: 'Введите имя',
                onValidationErrorMessage: 'Некорректное имя',
            }),
            lastName: baseValidate({
                validationType: 'name',
                validationValue: values['lastName'],
                onEmptyErrorMessage: 'Введите фамилию',
                onValidationErrorMessage: 'Некорректная фамилия',
            })
        }
}
```

Comment: Подставлять названия ключа, нет?

Comment: Что за задача такая?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9907419/how-to-get-a-key-in-a-javascript-object-by-its-value

Comment: @RavenTheX, а возможно ли узнать имя ключа не по значению как в примере, который ты скинул, а из значения, не указывая никаких аргументов для поиска, то есть значение хочет знать имя своего ключа:)

Comment: Если я правильно понимаю, простых способов нет. `firstName` вы присваиваете значение, возвращаемое `baseValidate()`, и в вызове функции нет возможности получить автоматически имя ключа, которому результат вызова присваивается. Если бы `firstName` было методом или геттером и вызов `baseValidate()` был внутри них, можно было бы использовать `arguments.callee.name`, но в strict mode `arguments.callee` deprecated. Можно заморочиться и использовать Proxy, но для такой сложности должно быть какое-то серьёзное основание.

Comment: @vsemozhetbyt , спасибо за ответ